# Integral with n-th term

Tags: integration

Evaluate an integral $$I_n=\int\frac{1}{(x^2+a^2)^n}dx$$ and determine $I_3$.

How to integrals with $n$-th term?

Comment: Compute $\int\frac{dx}{x^2+A}$ under the assumption $A>0$ and apply repeated differentiation with respect to the $A$-variable.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Recursive calculation: do an integration by parts of $I_n$ to obtain a relation between $I_n$ and $I_{n+1}$. $I_1$ is standard.